# Execute js loop on multiple parent nodes and their children

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to assign column classes to a table. The reason I am doing this on the fly is because there is adding/removing functionality and so I need to reassign classes dynamically.

Here is an example of the table structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Row 1 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Column C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="row"> 
            <td>Row 2 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Row 3 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 3 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 3 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
    </tboady>
</table>
```

And I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="a">Row 1 - Column A</td>
            <td class="b">Row 1 - Column B</td>
            <td class="c">Row 1 - Column C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="row"> 
            <td class="a">Row 2 - Column A</td>
            <td class="b">Row 2 - Column B</td>
            <td class="c">Row 2 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="a">Row 3 - Column A</td>
            <td class="b">Row 3 - Column B</td>
            <td class="c">Row 3 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
    </tboady>
</table>
```

I have created a For Loop to go through each row and assign the classes however the issue I am having is that instead of looping each row the for loop continues through all  elements and I am getting the wrong classes assigned.

```
 function updateColumnClasses() {
     var columnCountLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
     var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.row td');
     for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
         elements[i].setAttribute("class", columnCountLetters[i]);
     }
}

// Result
<table>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="a">Row 1 - Column A</td>
            <td class="b">Row 1 - Column B</td>
            <td class="c">Row 1 - Column C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="row"> 
            <td class="d">Row 2 - Column A</td>
            <td class="e">Row 2 - Column B</td>
            <td class="f">Row 2 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="g">Row 3 - Column A</td>
            <td class="h">Row 3 - Column B</td>
            <td class="i">Row 3 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
    </tboady>
</table>
```

Comment: If you only need the first 3 classes (a,b,c) you can just use modulo operator in your loop: `elements[i].setAttribute('class', columnCountLetters[i % 3]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop each  `tr` elements and  get the child `td`s

```js
function updateColumnClasses() {
     var columnCountLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
     const trElms = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
     trElms.forEach(tr => {
       for (var i = 0; i < tr.children.length; i++) {
          tr.children[i].setAttribute("class", columnCountLetters[i]);
       }    
     });
}

updateColumnClasses();
```

```css
.a {
color: red;
}

.b {
color:green;
}
.c {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Row 1 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Column C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="row"> 
            <td>Row 2 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Row 3 - Column A</td>
            <td>Row 3 - Column B</td>
            <td>Row 3 - Column C</td>
        </tr>
    </tboady>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do that:

```js
const columnCountLetters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

document.querySelectorAll('#table-body > tr.row').forEach(TR=>
  {
  for(let c = 0; c < TR.cells.length; c++)
    TR.cells[c].className = columnCountLetters[c]
  })
```

```css
.a { color : green }
.b { color : red }
.c { color : blue }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr class="row">
          <td>Row 1 - Column A</td>
          <td>Row 1 - Column B</td>
          <td>Row 1 - Column C</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row"> 
          <td>Row 2 - Column A</td>
          <td>Row 2 - Column B</td>
          <td>Row 2 - Column C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
          <td>Row 3 - Column A</td>
          <td>Row 3 - Column B</td>
          <td>Row 3 - Column C</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a dream!